# Handlebars multi select

Tags: javascript, json, handlebars.js

Did not found any good answer to this.
I have JSON

```
{colors:['Red','Orange']}
```

Html

```
<select multiple>
 <option value="">None</option>
 <option value="Red">Red</option>
 <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
 <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
</select>
```

How would you select only Red and Orange based on JSON above in multi select list with Handlebars, I have red helper docs for 'each' helper wont work , is there any elegant solution for this. I thought this was trivial but I found it very difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create helper like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('select', function(value, options) {

    var select = document.createElement('select');
    select.innerHTML = options.fn(this);

    [].forEach.call(select.options, function(option) {
        if (value.indexOf(option.value) > -1) {
            option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
        }
    });

    return select.innerHTML;
});
```

and use it in template:

```
<select multiple>
    {{#select colors}}
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
    {{/select}}
</select>
```